# Overwrite connection string stored in app.config in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, app-config

Hi I am developing an application for that I am taking connection string through dynamically from user at first time run.

My app.config is

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="DConnection" connectionString=""
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
 <add name="SConnection" connectionString="" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

I am assigning connection string to app.config's attributes by using below methods

```
private void CheckingSource(string constr)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["SConnection"].ConnectionString = constr; //CONCATINATE YOUR FIELDS TOGETHER HERE
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }

private void CheckingDestination(string constr)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DConnection"].ConnectionString = constr; //CONCATINATE YOUR FIELDS TOGETHER HERE
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }
```

Now I have to write this connection string to app.config so when user run application next time these updated connection strings should be in use.

How can we manage it? I don't have any idea as I am still fresher to app.config and it's usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now I have to write this connection string to app.config so when user run application next time these updated connection strings should be in use.

You shouldn't do this, the `app.config` file might be deployed to somewhere like `C:\Program Files\Your Application` which is **not** writeable by normal users.

Instead, supply the connection string to whatever needs it in some way other than using `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionStringFromUser())) { ...
```

With specific regards to "saving" a connection string, you should look at some sort of persistence mechanism like .NET's [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The application settings architecture supports defining strongly typed settings with either application or user scope, and persisting the settings between application sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ta.speot.is resolved the issue using application setting.

Reference link.
[Application Setting](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9a3ae2/arrange-application-setting-in-windows-form-application/)

might be helpful to all needy. Cheers.. :)